# Como fazer um grid automático para medidas exatas usando SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, matemática, scss, less

Tenho o seguinte exemplo mas em porcentagem:

```
$grid__cols: 12;
@for $i from 1 through $grid__cols {
  .col-#{$i} {
    flex-basis: (100 / ($grid__cols / $i) ) * 1%;
  }
}
```

Que pode ser [testado aqui](https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/), para gerar o CSS automaticamente.

Como eu poderia aplicar a mesma regra em pixel só que respeitando as 12 colunas com as mediadas exatas do grid de 76.7px / 12px até um total da largura 1272px?

Exemplo de grid:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa fórmula vai fazer a progressão das colunas em `PX` até `1272px`

```
$grid__cols: 12;
@for $i from 1 through $grid__cols {
  .col-#{$i} {
    flex-basis: (1272 / ($grid__cols / $i) ) * 1px;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.col-1 {
  flex-basis: 106px;
}
.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 212px;
}
.col-3 {
  flex-basis: 318px;
}
.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 424px;
}
.col-5 {
  flex-basis: 530px;
}
.col-6 {
  flex-basis: 636px;
}
.col-7 {
  flex-basis: 742px;
}
.col-8 {
  flex-basis: 848px;
}
.col-9 {
  flex-basis: 954px;
}
.col-10 {
  flex-basis: 1060px;
}
.col-11 {
  flex-basis: 1166px;
}
.col-12 {
  flex-basis: 1272px;
}
```

---

E essa formula vai criar `12 colunas` de `76.7px`, o que não faze sentido algum, pq vc iria querer uma classe com `col-12`, mas que tem a mesma largura em px da `col-6` O.o

```
$grid__cols: 12;
@for $i from 1 through $grid__cols {
  .col-#{$i} {
    flex-basis: 76.7px;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.col-1 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-2 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-3 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-5 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-6 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-7 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-8 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-9 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-10 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-11 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
.col-12 {
  flex-basis: 76.7px;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, era isso mesmo que eu queria!

Comment: @IvanFerrer legal  que ajudou, mas estou atualizando a resposta, ela tinha um erro na primeira fórmula que usei na resposta, antes a col-6 da primeira fórmula não tinha 1/2 do total da largura do Grid, ou seja, não era 636px (1272 / 2). Mas agora está certinho!

Comment: Obrigado, excelente!